# Regex Case Sensitivity Not working for Redux-Forms

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to do a password validation in a React/Redux build using Redux-Forms. Everything is working great except I can't seem to get it to prevent passwords with at least one uppercase letter. Here is my regex:

```
^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).+$
```

It works fine in a regex validator and in my form validator, it works except for the uppercase letter.

```
const password = value =>
 value && !/^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).+$/i.test(value)
  ? 'Passwords must at least 8 characters, include one capital letter, one number, and one special character:'
  : undefined;
```

We are also using Wizard-Form but I don't see anything in there that would be messing with the case.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has a case insensitive match due to the /i flag at the end.
Simply remove the `/i` at the end of your regex to make this work:

```
> /^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).+$/i.test('hello1*')
true
> /^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).+$/.test('hello1*')
false
```

Comment: Thank you! That saved me quite s bit of time.